# Удаление элементов из ArrayList<Object> в Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-linearlayout

В Android-приложении у меня реализован функционал по динамическому добавлению `textView` в `linearLayout`, и увеличению высоты этого `Layout`:

```
final View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.strings_layout, null);
                final TextView text = (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.txtview);
                text.setText(iing.getName());
                params.height = params.height + layoutpar;
                linear.setLayoutParams(params);
                allEds.add(view2);
                linear.addView(view2);
```

На каждом `textView` висит событие `text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`, в котором одной из операций является операция получения индекса нажатого `textView` и сохранения всех `view`, у которых `index` меньше данного индекса:

```
int position=allEds.indexOf(view2);
                        for (int k=0; k<allEds.size();k++)
                        {
                            if (position>k)
                            {
                                allEdsdop.add(allEds.get(k));
                            }
                        }
```

После нажатия на `textView`, получения индекса нажатого `textView` и копирования `view` в другой `ListArray`, происходит набор операций, среди которых происходит удаление всех `view` с `textView`, `index` которых меньше значения `position`. Удаление происходит таким способом:

```
linear.removeAllViews();
                    params.height =0;//обнуляю высоту layout
                    linear.setLayoutParams(params); 
                    allEds=new ArrayList<View>(); //очищаю весь список view
                    allEds=allEdsdop; //присваиваю ему значение сохраненных ранее, у которых index меньше postition
                    for (int k=0; k<allEds.size();k++) //в цикле заново создаю и размещаю textview в layout, и устанавливаю высоту
                    {
                        params.height =params.height+layoutpar;
                        linear.setLayoutParams(params);
                        linear.addView(allEds.get(k));
                    }
```

И кроме этого, после последнего элемента в списке, создается еще один `textView` и так далее.

Проблема в том, что после первого удаления, когда весь процесс прошел, на экране остался список `textView` с `index` меньше `position` + новый созданный `textview`, у ВСЕХ `textView`, которые не были удалены(с `index` меньше `position`) пропадает событие  `text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`. Оно есть только у новых `textView`, которые создаются после удаления и восстановления старых `textView`. То бишь при нажатии на эти textView не происходит ничего.

Есть ли способ удаления элементов их `ArraList<>` без создания копий этого `ArrayList<>` с `view`, которые не надо удалять и затем обратного создания всех элементов на экране, чтобы событие `setOnClickListener` не пропадало у них? 
Я смотрел, что можно использовать механизм `Iterator`, но я так и не понял как его использовать в моем случае и как он работает с `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

Вот способ удаления элементов `ArrayList` без создания копии элементов и использования `Iterator`, хитрость в том, чтобы пройтись по листу не с нулевого значения, а с конца, тогда можно построить такой цикл:

```
for (int i=arrayList.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if (...) {
      arrayList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

что позволит удалить нужные значения!